# How can I upload image directly on Amazon S3 in React Native?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-native

I am going to upload image on Amazon S3 in React Native.

I have S3 signedUrl for uploading image.

How can I upload image using this url in React Native?

If anybody tried this, please help me.

Thank you!

Comment: What are you supposed to do with the URL?  It is just a POST? If so, just make the request using FETCH. More details would be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

It's quite simple, I spent a lot of time to discover that:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhr.status === 200) {
      // success
    } else {
      // failure
    }
  }
}
xhr.open('PUT', presignedUrl)
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', fileType)
xhr.send({ uri: filePath, type: fileType, name: fileName })
```

- **filePath** is the full path to the file
- **fileType** is the mime type of the file
- **fileName** is the file name

source: http://blog.rudikovac.com/react-native-upload-any-file-to-s3-with-a-presigned-url/

Comment: I should point out that the presigned url must have been signed with the Content-Type (like 'image/png', etc.). This client side code wasn't working until we signed correctly on the server side as well.

Answer (score 1):

You can just use `fetch` as following:

```
import { ImagePickerIOS } from 'react-native';

ImagePickerIOS.openSelectDialog({},(assetUri)=>{
  var photo = {
    uri: assetUri,
    type: 'image/jpeg',
    name: 'main.jpg'
  }

  var body = new FormData();
  body.append('file', photo);

  fetch(presignedUrl, {
    method: 'put', body: body
  });
},()=>{ console.log('failed'); })
```

Comment: Did you test it?

Comment: sure! this my code snippet in past. you also need to have backend to generate `s3 presignedUrl `

Comment: It does not work. You can't submit form data using PUT. You need to read the documentation before post your answer or even test your code. Section 9.6 http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt

Comment: you are wrong! see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjectPreSignedURLRubySDK.html. given s3 presignedUrl, you need to use http `put` method to upload.

Comment: You can't submit FORM DATA using PUT method, you should send your file as a body, not a form data as a body, you know?

Comment: I dont want to waste my time to argue with you. please validate the code by yourself. the arrow function of code is really on my working project. oh.. please also generate your s3 presignedUrl first.

Answer (score 0):

```
  const file = {
        uri: response.uri,
        name: "image.png",
        type: "image/png"
      }

      const options = {
      keyPrefix: "",
      bucket: "",
      region: "",
      accessKey: "",
      secretKey: "",
      successActionStatus: 200
     }

     RNS3.put(file, options).then(response => {
       if (response.status !== 200)
       alert(response.body);
       else {
//Success## 


----------


 ##
         alert(JSON.stringify(response))

       }
     });
```